# Does apache have a limit to cookie size?

Tags: apache-2.2, cookies

A application bug caused us to set a cookie that's too large.

Clients get an error that happens prior to our application being executed (mod_python).

Are there any adjustable limits within apache for how large a cookie header can be ?

Within apache error logs, I'm seeing: `request failed: error reading the headers`

Answer (score 4):

See the [LimitRequestLine directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) in Apache's configuration.  The default is 8190 so anything bigger than that has the potential to cause problems.

> This directive sets the number of
>   bytes that will be allowed on the HTTP
>   request-line.
>
> The LimitRequestLine directive allows
>   the server administrator to reduce or
>   increase the limit on the allowed size
>   of a client's HTTP request-line. Since
>   the request-line consists of the HTTP
>   method, URI, and protocol version, the
>   LimitRequestLine directive places a
>   restriction on the length of a
>   request-URI allowed for a request on
>   the server. A server needs this value
>   to be large enough to hold any of its
>   resource names, including any
>   information that might be passed in
>   the query part of a GET request.
>
> This directive gives the server
>   administrator greater control over
>   abnormal client request behavior,
>   which may be useful for avoiding some
>   forms of denial-of-service attacks.

I believe this is the limit of the sum of all cookies on a web page and not just an individual cookie (not positive on that though).  But all the cookies for a website are transmitted using the a single request header, so if enough cookies are on a webpage and the sum exceeds the value of the LimitRequestLine directive, there will be problems.

Comment: Actually, I think for cookies we want 'LimitRequestFieldSize' right ?

Comment: Yep it can also help, but keep in mind that LimitRequestLine sets the overall Request size, containing all the fields. so you cannot have a Field size (or LimitRequestFieldSize) > LimitRequestLine.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that to set it higher then default you need to rebuild the source, the docs states: "Also, you can't set this higher than 8190 without modifying the source and rebuilding."